# Update input values for form live preview (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, forms, dom, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a form with several inputs, for which I have live preview in Ruby on Rails app. Live preview works fine, until it comes to previewing form with existing record.

if my object is not created, I see something like this (note there is no "value" attribute)

```
<input class="deal_title" id="deal_title" name="deal[title]" type="text">
```

If I fill in the form and send it to the server, inputs "value"'s attributes are being assigned with user-entered values, so if I open the form source I see:

```
<input class="deal_title" id="deal_title" name="deal[title]" type="text" value="New offer">
```

I have a script to bind live preview:

```
  $("#new_deal input").keyup ->
    css_klass = $(this).attr("class")
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val())
    inpt = $(this).val()
    $("." + css_klass + "_preview").html inpt
```

If I reproduce the same in JsFiddle, it works fine:

[JsFiddle without "value"](http://jsfiddle.net/ARVcy/)

[JsFiddle with "value"](http://jsfiddle.net/P2yVS/)

However in my Rails app, this only works in the first case (if no value is set). in the second case, nothing just happens and value stays the same. I copied inputs from my app, directly from the view.  I use Rails 4 with turbolinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself!

This happens because rails applies custom ID to forms depending on action. If it is "New" action, then ID would be "new_object". If it is "Edit" action, then class would be "edit_object".

I applied custom class like:

```
<%= form_for(@deal, html: { "data-abide" => '', id: "deal_form"}, builder: SmartLabelFormBuilder) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

and

```
$("#deal_form input").keyup ->
    css_klass = $(this).attr("class")
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val())
    inpt = $(this).val()
    $("." + css_klass + "_preview").html inpt
```

And it works.